# React navigation 5 - drawer - update items with localization

Tags: android, react-native, localization, locale, react-navigation-drawer

Based on the documentation [you can create a custom drawer with react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent).

Implementing i18n isn't difficult. But what I see is :
The `DrawerItem` from the `CustomDrawerContent` are properly updated when we change the `i18n.locale`.
But everything else that was sent through `Drawer.Navigator drawerContent` is kind of **frozen**. Basically every `Drawer.Screen` item...

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      // DrawerItemList contains MyDrawer content.
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label={i18n.t('some.definition10')} onPress={() => alert(i18n.t('some.definition99')} /> // Label i18n string will update properly but not the Alert (minor issue).
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="menu1" component={SomeComponent1} options={{ drawerLabel: i18n.t('some.definition1') }}     // Will not update drawerLabel
      <Drawer.Screen name="menu2" component={SomeComponent2} options={{ drawerLabel: i18n.t('some.definition2') }}     // Will not update drawerLabel    
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Working Drawer+I18n code on snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@tex/drawer-i18n-update).

---

My understanding of this is:

- `MyDrawer` is called.
- then the `Drawer.Navigator drawerContent` will make `CustomDrawerContent` take over `MyDrawer`.

So the whole thing is processed now like the following:

-> `CustomDrawerContent` having `MyDrawer` as a child element while the declaration is kind of the opposite. It looks like an [ourobouros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros).

I tried to reshape the code in a class thinking it would be more dynamic: no success.

---

**So the question is**: How to make the `Drawer.Screen` elements in the `CustomDrawerContent` update properly when changing `i18n.locale`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by utilizing the `props` that is passed.

The `props` has a "descriptors" key that contains all the drawer screen information. So it would look something like this.

```
{
   "descriptors": {
        "Drawer-1-some-code": {
            ....
            "options": {
                  "drawerLabel": "label"
                  ...
            }
        }
        ...
   }
}
```

So you need to call the i18n.t on the `drawerLabel` here. Which can be done in the following way.

```
Object.keys(this.props.descriptors).forEach( key => {
   if('drawerLabel' in this.props.descriptors[key].options) {
        this.props.descriptors[key].options.drawerLabel = i18n.t(
          this.props.descriptors[key].options.drawerLabel,
       );
   }
});
```

You can put this in the start of the render function.